# VSCode latex snippet : bypass the "\" character

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, code-snippets

I'm using VSCode and [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips), and would like to know how to code a snippet to bypass the "" character, which is tedious to write using French AZERTY keyboards. The idea would be to transform a word related to a LaTeX command to this command by pressing tab.

In a nutshell, to do this :

```js
snippet mu "transform mu into \mu" flags
\mu
endsnippet
```

but generalized to each LaTeX command.

Comment: So, you have a bunch of latex commands and you want to output `\` in front of all of them?  How many are there - I am not familiar with laTeX - but this could be done with a regex key.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, haven't seen my notification. Yeah, regex could be useful, if I find a list of all commands. I don't know if some are available on the web, but still there are a bunch of them, hundreds if not thousands !

Answer (score 1):

You could try a snippet like this:

```
snippet `\b(\w*)\.` "Add \ to start" A
\``rv = m[1]``$0
endsnippet
```

where you can see I used a `.` as a unique character to trigger the snippet - I'm sure there are better ones like a `?` or `2` or whatever is convenient and not used in a laTex - that trailing "trigger" could be more than one character of course, like `..` or whatever.  Demo (the gif never shows typing the `.` at the end to transform the command but that is what I am doing):

[image: latex HyperSnip snippet]